How do I cooperatively stop another process in PowerShell?
The following starts another PowerShell process which logs to a file.  That process is then stopped with Stop-Process:
{
    end {
        $logFile = "$PID`_log.txt"
        'started' | Set-Content $logFile
        while ($true) {[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(100)}
    }
    clean { 'clean' | Add-Content $logFile }
} |
    Set-Content .\probe.ps1

$process = Start-Process -FilePath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList .\probe.ps1 -PassThru
$logFile = "$($process.Id)`_log.txt"
do { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10 }
while (-not (Test-Path $logFile))

$process | Stop-Process

do { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10 }
while (Get-Process -Id $process.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

Get-Content $logFile

This outputs
started

which indicates that clean{} was not run.  If, on the other hand, the Stop-Process line is removed and the resulting PowerShell console is interrupted with Ctrl+C the same outputs
started
clean

This seems to be a manifestation of Bug: Stop-Process does not issue SIGTERM as expected.
#13664 which remains unresolved and hasn't made much progress since 2021.  The above behavior seems to be confirmed by this comment:

This seems to be the case that it jumps straight to Kill instead of requesting close

So how do I cooperatively request another process to stop from PowerShell?

Is using Start-Job not an option in this case? The way you could handle exiting gracefully using Start-Process could be via Named Pipe

@SantiagoSquarzon Launching another instance of pwsh.exe is just so that the repro is portable.  It could just as easily have been notepad.exe which is the example often used for processes without a console.  I am looking for a solution in general, but I'll take whatever I can get.

Not sure how useful it can be for your use case but using a NamedPipeConnectionInfo does work ending the script gracefully. Main difference with a Job is that Jobs don't outlive their parent process. The issue clearly isn't related to Stop-Process but with the underlying TerminateProcess function.
$script = {
    param($path)

    end {
        'started' | Set-Content $path
        while ($true) {
            [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(100)
        }
    }
    clean {
        'clean' | Add-Content $path
    }
}

try {
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList '-nop', '-noninteractive' -PassThru
    $path = Join-Path $pwd "$($process.Id)_log.txt"
    $pipe = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($process.Id)
    $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($pipe)
    $rs.Open()
    $ps = [powershell]::Create($rs).AddScript($script).AddArgument($path)
    $null = $ps.InvokeAsync()
    while (-not (Test-Path $path)) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 }
    $ps.Stop()
}
finally {
    ${ps}?.Dispose()
    ${rs}?.Dispose()
    ${process}?.Kill()
}

Get-Content $path


"This isn't very different than using a normal Job though." Indeed, that does look like a job.



Unfortunately, as of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.5.0, Stop-Process invariably performs forceful termination of the target process, which doesn't give the process a chance to clean up, which in your case prevents the clean block from running.

It is unclear whether Stop-Process will ever alternatively support requesting graceful termination, by opt-in, via a potential future -TryGraceful switch, as discussed in the GitHub issue you link to, GitHub issue #13664; as you note, the discussion has stalled, unfortunately.


Graceful termination requires calling the System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow() .NET method or calling taskkill.exe without /F, but note the following constraints:

Only GUI applications and console applications that directly own a console window can be targeted this way.

Targeted applications must be designed to handle such cooperative termination requests:

(a) GUI-subsystem applications must perform any cleanup in response to receiving a WM_CLOSE message.

(b) Console-subsystem applications - if they directly own a console (conhost.exe) window - must register for and handle CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT console events via the SetConsoleCtrlHandler WinAPI function.

Note that this implies that console-subsystem applications that do not own a console window can not generally be terminated gracefully:

Unfortunately, this implies that console applications running in Windows Terminal can not be gracefully terminated this way.

For applications running in regular console windows (those created by the legacy console host, conhost.exe), this applies to console applications that were launched by other console applications, notably from shells (it is only the process that initially caused the creation of the console that owns it).

Other processes that cannot be terminated gracefully are those running as Windows services - use dedicated commands such as Stop-Service for that.



Targeting ineligible processes with taskkill.exe (without /f) results in the following error message, reflecting that fact:
 ERROR: The process with PID <pid> could not be terminated.
 Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).










pwsh.exe, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI, falls into category (b), i.e. it does handle CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT events - see the source code.

Caveat: As noted above, the following only applies to PowerShell sessions running in regular console windows (provided by the legacy console host, conhost.exe), as opposed to those running in Windows Terminal.

Therefore, you should be able to perform graceful termination by replacing:
$process | Stop-Process

with:
$process.CloseMainWindow()

Unfortunately, however - and this appears to be a bug - as of PowerShell 7.5.0 this does not work: while it seems that the clean block is called, it isn't given enough time to finish.

Commendably, you have since filed GitHub issue #24631 to report this problem.


"Targeted applications must be designed to handle such cooperative termination requests..." This fact combined with what seems to be a variety of possible methods of signaling that termination request means that I expect that on Windows a command cannot be implemented that reliably requests successful cooperative termination of an arbitrary process.

"...you should be able to perform graceful termination...however - and this appears to be a bug - ...this does not work." I have opened github #24631 accordingly.

Thanks for opening the GitHub issue, @alx9r - I've added a link to the answer. As for cooperative termination of an arbitrary process: Conceptually, there is indeed no and there cannot be a guarantee that cleanup will be performed, in the absence of being able to guarantee that any and all processes are designed to handle cooperative termination. Technically, a runtime underlying a given process, such as .NET in the case of PowerShell, may implement at least partial cleanup at a lower level.

@alx9r, I've updated the answer to point out that graceful termination of console applications running in Windows Terminal is currently unsupported. That said, I still think the behavior in regular console windows is a bug: it seems that cleanup is started, but not given a chance to finish. I'll eventually weigh in on the GitHub issue.

"...the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI, falls into category (b), i.e. it does handle CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT events..." I put a demo of what seems to be a robust way of doing that (at least on Windows) here.

GitHub issue #24631 concluded with the technique from this answer as the resolution.
